# Access Header generate from base64

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, postman

For each API request, the header needs to be modified and I have a pre-request script from Postman like this:

```
var Authentication = "";
Authentication += pm.collectionVariables.get( "TokenHead" );
Authentication += "." + pm.collectionVariables.get( "TokenTail" );
Authentication = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse( Authentication ));

pm.request.headers.add("Authentication: basic " + Authentication );
```

How can I access the header? The API requires a TokenHead and TokenTail for the request, and the tokens are stored in local storage.

```
const TokenHead = localStorage.getItem('TokenHead');
const TokenTail = localStorage.getItem('TokenTail');
const Authentication = `${TokenHead}.${TokenTail}`;
const EncodedAuthentication = btoa(Authentication);

const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Authorization: `Basic ${EncodedAuthentication}`,
};

await axios
  .post(vURL, vData, headers)
  .then((vResponse) => {
    vStatus = vResponse.data.Status;
  });
```

Comment: Make sure you have stored the token header and tail in the local storage.

Comment: I have made sure that when signing in, I bring tokenhead and tokentail in local storage and the data is in the form of an array. 

When I try to access features related to the API, I receive a response of 'authentication invalid.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is decode a header

```
JSON.parse(Buffer.from(header, 'base64').toString())
```

Example

Decode with `header` input data

```
item = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9'
JSON.parse(Buffer.from(item, 'base64').toString())
```

Output of Decode

```
{ alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' }
```

I think you needs to replace from '.' to ':' for `base64` string for Authentication.

From

```
const Authentication = `${TokenHead}.${TokenTail}`;
```

To

```
const Authentication = `${TokenHead}:${TokenTail}`;
```

Examples for this format
In [here](https://developerhub.dmtispatial.com/basic-authentication/#:%7E:text=Basic%20Authentication%20sends%20a%20Base64,transmitted%20over%20a%20TLS%20v1.)

[image]

[There](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/)
[image]

#### Demo example of `How to decode a header`

Node.JS is cross-platform compatible, just like React.
You can definitely use Node JS with React framework.

```js
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js")
const LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage

const parseJwt = (item) => {
    return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(item, 'base64').toString())
}

// storage location
localStorage = new LocalStorage('./my-data')

// sample token
const token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c'
const tokenSplit = token.split(".")

// save token
localStorage.setItem('TokenHead', tokenSplit[0])
localStorage.setItem('TokenBody', tokenSplit[1])
localStorage.setItem('TokenTail', tokenSplit[2])

// load token
const TokenHead = localStorage.getItem('TokenHead')
const TokenBody = localStorage.getItem('TokenBody')
const TokenTail = localStorage.getItem('TokenTail')


const Authentication = TokenHead + '.' + TokenTail

// eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
console.log(Authentication)

const EncodedAuthentication1 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse( Authentication ));
// ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LlNmbEt4d1JKU01lS0tGMlFUNGZ3cE1lSmYzNlBPazZ5SlZfYWRRc3N3NWM=
console.log(EncodedAuthentication1)

const EncodedAuthentication2 = btoa(TokenHead + '.' + TokenTail);
// ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LlNmbEt4d1JKU01lS0tGMlFUNGZ3cE1lSmYzNlBPazZ5SlZfYWRRc3N3NWM=
console.log(EncodedAuthentication2)

const DecodeAuthentication2  = atob(EncodedAuthentication2)
// eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
console.log(DecodeAuthentication2)

const tokenBack = DecodeAuthentication2.split(".");

// eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
console.log(tokenBack[0])

// { alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' }
console.log(parseJwt(tokenBack[0]))

// { sub: '1234567890', name: 'John Doe', iat: 1516239022 }
console.log(parseJwt(TokenBody))

// SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
console.log(tokenBack[1])
```

Install dependencies

```
npm install crypto-js node-localstorage
```

Result

```
$ node test.js
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LlNmbEt4d1JKU01lS0tGMlFUNGZ3cE1lSmYzNlBPazZ5SlZfYWRRc3N3NWM=
ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LlNmbEt4d1JKU01lS0tGMlFUNGZ3cE1lSmYzNlBPazZ5SlZfYWRRc3N3NWM=
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
{ alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' }
{ sub: '1234567890', name: 'John Doe', iat: 1516239022 }
SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

From this test, those two function's results are same.

#1 using `CryptoJS`

```
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse( TokenHead + '.' + TokenTail))
```

And #2 using `btoa`

```
btoa(TokenHead + '.' + TokenTail)
```

Decode is using `atob`

```
atob(EncodedAuthentication2)
```

#### Post call demo using `localstorage`

This is real POST calling for get token of `Spotify` using `localstorage`.

Save as `get-token.js` file name.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const base64 = require('base-64')

const LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage
localStorage = new LocalStorage('./my-data')

const storeToken = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('ClientId', '<your Spotify ClientId>')
    localStorage.setItem('ClientSecret', '<your Spotify Secret>')
}

const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const URL='https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
        const client_id = localStorage.getItem('ClientId')
        const client_secret = localStorage.getItem('ClientSecret')
        const response = await axios.post(URL,
            new URLSearchParams({
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
            }),
            {
                headers:
                {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret)
                }
            })
        return Promise.resolve(response.data)
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
};

storeToken()

getToken()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message)
    })
```

Install dependencies

```
npm install axios base-64 node-localstorage
```

Result of Authorization

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering and helping me,
but my backend uses PHP framework Laravel Apache, is it also possible? I will give it a try, thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, I have no experience for PHP framework Laravel. It seems can using Axios but needs to change a bit example in [here](https://pusher.com/tutorials/laravel-vue-axios/), Good Luck!